# How to use ProtectedRoute (RequireAuth) with fetch(url, method) in React (React Router v6)?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router, fetch, react-state

I want to redirect users to Unprotected (login/ register) components if the user is not logged in (or verified) else allow access to Protected components.

To achieve that, I tried to use,

---

### ProtectedRoute techniques

- [PrivateRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476186/when-user-is-not-logged-in-redirect-to-login-reactjs) *- failed to implement appropriately*
- [RequiresLogin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164554/how-to-implement-authenticated-routes-in-react-router-4) ***- This helped me to reach to the next approach***
- And some YouTube videos and articles found from Google

**Code:**

index.js

```js
...
<Router>
    <App />
</Router>
...
```

App.js *- using the ProtectedRoute*

```js
...
<Routes>
    <ProtectedRoute exact path={"page1"} element={<Page1 />}/>
    <ProtectedRoute exact path={"page2"} element={<Page2 />}/>
    <Route exact path={"login"} element={<Login />}/>
<Routes/>
...
```

---

### RequireAuth

It seemed that it is a better approach then **ProtectedRoute**,

- [RequireAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384395/protected-route-with-react-router-v6) *- works except, it is ProtectiveOverflow at the moment*

**Code:**

index.js

```js
// Unchanged
```

App.js

```js
...
<Routes>
    <Route exact path={"page1"} element={
        <RequireAuth>
            <Page1 />
        </RequireAuth>
     }/>
    <Route exact path={"page2"} element={
        <RequireAuth>
            <Page2 />
        </RequireAuth>
     }/>
    <Route exact path={"login"} element={<Login />}/>
</Routes>
...
```

It seemed to work and I was able to protect the protected components. After implementing the authorization process, which I am doing by sending a `fetch(...)` request to my API (djangorestframework) and getting the result dynamically everytime, I figured out that the protected components got a bit more protective than required. Now, although the server authenticating the request and sending sucessfull response, the protected pages are still locked.

Digging up, I realized that I have used the fetch function which is a `Promise` and it runs on a separate thread. So, before the fetch could return the result, my component already gets rendered and unmounted.

**Code:**

RequireAuth.js

```js
...
function RequireAuth({children}) {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
    
    fetch(urls.auth, methods.get())
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => {
            setAuth(data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    
    return auth? children : <Navigate to={"../login"}/>;
}
...
```

---

I have gone through various technique to solve this, for example,

- [Using statefull component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611631/reactjs-protected-route-with-api-call)

**Code:**

RequireAuth.js

```js
...
class RequireAuth extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {auth: false}

        fetch(urls.auth, methods.get())
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({auth: data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.auth? this.props.children : <Navigate to={"../login"}/>;
    }
}
...
```

---

### However, that failed too. Then I looked into,

- [Fetch data and then render it to dom React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341624/fetch-data-and-then-render-it-to-dom-react)
- [Web Fetch API (waiting the fetch to complete and then executed the next instruction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775517/web-fetch-api-waiting-the-fetch-to-complete-and-then-executed-the-next-instruct)
- [Trying to implement a SIMPLE promise in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029867/trying-to-implement-a-simple-promise-in-reactjs)
- [How to return data from promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533929/how-to-return-data-from-promise)
- [How to get data returned from fetch() promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604040/how-to-get-data-returned-from-fetch-promise)
- [How to finish all fetch before executing next function in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980247/how-to-finish-all-fetch-before-executing-next-function-in-react)

---

### Finally,

I looked if I can do it using fetching or HttpRequest methods that does not run on different thread, but I afraid, even if it's possible, it can result in bad user experience. Therefore, please help me to solve this `fetch authentication` issue in React. And, I would also like if there were other ways to implement the dynamic authorization using `React` and `djangorestframework` that could do this protective page stuffs more efficiently.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59477830/6520695) on StackOverflow as I could not stop searching just because I asked a question. This is very exciting and sad at the same time. I missed one very small part, I thought maybe it was not a very big deal. But guess what?

---

### `null` is important

---

Yes, `null` is what I was missing while returning in my code. So, what I figured is if `null` is returned, react won't consider it as rendered and the render request will be keep asking, that's what I beleive. So I can simple set the default state of `auth` to be null and return `null` if it is `null`, else check the value of `auth`.

**Code:**

index.js

```js
// Unchanged
...
<Router>
    <App />
</Router>
...
```

App.js

```js
// Unchanged
...
<Routes>
    <Route exact path={"page1"} element={
        <RequireAuth>
            <Page1 />
        </RequireAuth>
     }/>
    <Route exact path={"page2"} element={
        <RequireAuth>
            <Page2 />
        </RequireAuth>
     }/>
    <Route exact path={"login"} element={<Login />}/>
</Routes>
...
```

RequireAuth.js *- this is interesting*

```js
...
// Assumption: The server is sending `true` or `false` as the response for authentication for simplicity
function RequireAuth({children}) {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);  // The spell for the magic

    fetch(urls.auth, methods.get())
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => setAuth(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    return auth == null?  // The code that did the magic
        null : (auth?
            children : <Navigate to={"/login"}/>)  // Notice, used '/login' instead of 'login' to directly go to login/ authenticate page which is at the root path.
...
```